# Encrypt & Decrypt credit card using coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

Is there any way to **encrypt & decrypt** credit card details with custom key using **ColdFusion**?

I have tried with JAVA file (Should i  post the code?).

there is the code in which am getting error.

```
<cfdump var="#CreateObject('JAVA','StrongAES')#"><cfabort>
```

I am getting **Server Error 500**

Thanks

Comment: Encryption  and decryption methods are there in coldFusion. what have you  tried so  far?

Comment: can you suggest me some. i have tried with little bit java code but not succeed....

Comment: You must post the code and actual problem you are facing. that will others to understand your problem.

Comment: why you are using java. you can do this using CF. see the ans below

Comment: I have used a below code and it works for me.
Thanks

Comment: While basic encryption may *seem* easy, [PCI compliance is not](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php), which is why most recommend against it. Before storing credit sure to understand the requirements and financial liabilities before storing credit card information.

Comment: What Leigh said. You should probably not be storing this information anywhere, even if encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use encrypt and decrypt methods to perform encryption and decryption. You can either user generate secret key or use your custom key to do that.
Here is what i will do.

```
<!--- To generate secret key (you can also use your custom key) --->
<cfset secretKey = generateSecretKey("AES") />

<!--- to encrypt --->
<cfset encryptedDetails = encrypt(cardDetails, secretKey , "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />

<!--- to decrypt --->

<cfset cardDetails= decrypt(encryptedDetails , secretKey , "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />
```

For more details see [Encrypt](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html) and [decrypt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c1c.html)

Comment: Just my 2¢, but any answer to a question containing the phrase *"I want to store credit cards..."* should at least mention there is a LOT more involved to proper storage of credit cards than just a simple encrypt/decrypt call.  There are very stringent requirements for PCI compliance and steep liabilities for failing, which is why most folks recommend *not* storing credit cards.

Comment: @Leigh completely agree with you. I should have mentioned this.